# What's the difference between 'pod spec lint' and 'pod lib lint'?

Tags: cocoapods

Cocoapods provides two lint commands, `spec lint` and `lib lint`. What's the exact different between them, and in what scenario are they each used?

I read the documentation ([spec](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_spec_lint), [lib](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_lib_lint)), but I can not find the difference between them, and I do not understand why Cocoapods provides two command for the same thing.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**TL;DR**: pod lib lint = local, pod spec lint = local/remote

---

You mentioned that you had read the docs but it's still unclear. I'll try to make it more clear :

### pod lib lint

It will `lint` your pod locally, and will just assume that you provided everything properly to create your pod (it won't make any attempts to fetch/download its dependencies). But it will not be enough to validate your pod, Only `pod spec lint` will.

## pod spec lint

It will `lint` your pod anywhere. You can have your pod source code on GitHub. The lint command would just work. If the `pod spec lint` returns without errors, you can push the linted pod up to Cocoapods.

Comment: Is that mean `pod spec lint` covers all tests of `pod lib lint`? And `pod spec lint` tests the pod more strict?

Comment: Yes, pod spec lint IS the ultimate way to test your pod spec against your library. I used pod lib lint before pushing my code on github, but now I use only pod spec lint, you should too